# NSPredicateRow with 2 values (e.g. "between")

Tags: nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

Does anyone know a elegant way to create a NSPredicateRowTemplate with 2 fields, like filtering for a range of NSDate : "between".

I could succeed to create a custom template, but then the question is how to manage the 2nd NSDatePicker. Especially as this must be converted into "BETWEEN {startdate,enddate}" and I do not want to modify the query string.

How the Predicate should look like :
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` subclass?

Comment: Yes, I did. As you can see, the view with an additional field appears as expected. But I do not see a way to define 2 fields to be taken into consideration for the query statement. DateRange is now set up as NSDateAttributeType ( works for the 1st field). It gives : dateRange == CAST(614882604.160126, "NSDate").

Comment: I have some approach, but it is ugly handicraft work: 1.) Set IBAction on 2nd Datepicker. 2.) get predicate and substitute the part od dateRange to between {}

Comment: See [predicate(withSubpredicates:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspredicateeditorrowtemplate/1401179-predicate) and take a look at the other primitive methods of `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`.